Need to handle memory leaks in long-running node processes, tools or strategies you find effective for memory management?
How do we handle memory leaks in long-running Node.js processes?
Am working on project in which memory leaks happening, if you suggest any tools or strategies you find effective for memory management?
am using node express.
Thanks
I did some code reviews and use eslint to detect some leaks, as well use Memory Leak Detection Libraries like memwatch-next & heapdump but no luck.
I was suggested to move over Nest JS for better features and more capability of doing stuff than node js.
